# MySQL: trouble copying data from one table to another based on matching ids

Tags: mysql, copy

i need to copy existing data from one table to another **based on matching fields**.  this is not a wholesale column dupe.

how it should work is: if the `id` in `asset` matches the `assetID` in `report`, then copy the `repEmail` field from the `report` table into the `rep_email` field in the asset table.  this is what i've built based on the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) for `insert...select`:

```sql
INSERT INTO asset (rep_email)
  SELECT report.repEmail
  FROM report WHERE report.assetID = asset.id
```

this throws: `Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'asset.id' in 'where clause'`.

i also tried this:

```sql
where safety_report.eNumber = asset_roster.id
insert into asset_roster (building_rep_email) 
select bldgRepEmail from safety_report;
```

but it errors on the first line.  :(

i'm not sure how to modify this to eliminate the error and properly write the values across.  it *seems* like it should be a simple operation... please advise.

NB: i do not have admin access to the tables. the reason for this seeming duplication has to do with permissions to the different tables.  and even if not, i'd need to write foreign keys anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want to update the column `rep_email` of `asset` with values from the column `repEmail` of `report`:

```
UPDATE asset a
INNER JOIN report r ON r.assetID = a.id
SET a.rep_email = r.repEmail
```

Comment: boom.  that did it.  i wondered if an `inner join` was the right way to go, but figured the docs would have led me there... they didn't.  you did.  thank you.  :)